# Javascript Angular 4 using eventEmitter though several layers of components

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having a bit of a problem with getting the following situation done in Angular.

I am using Angular 4 and this is the situation.

app.component.html contains a wrapper div which I would like to be able to change it's color by adding a class to it.

My problem is that I have different layers of components.

For example, if I wanted to change the class in app.component.html it would have this:

```
app.component - root

button-wrapper.component - holds the button

button.component - message comes from there.
```

Normally I could do this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  myClass = '';

  handleEvent(value) {
    console.log(value);
    myClass = value;
  }
}
```

and in app.component.html have this:

```
<div [ngClass]="myClass">

  <app-button (outputEvent)="handleEvent($event)"></app-button>

</div>
```

BUT, my problem is that app-button component is inside button-wrapper component so it looks like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="myClass">

    <button-wrapper></div>

</div>
```

So where would I put this:

```
(outputEvent)="handleEvent($event)"
```

How can I go round this issue?

Comment: `button-wrapper` is inside `AppComponent` ?

Comment: To use parent-child communication between multiple 'layers', each layer must input/output to those that are parent or child. Or you can use an 'shared service' to communicate between layers that are not parent/child as explained here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain events as long as their direct children:

**button.component.ts** (selector: app-button)

```
startChainEvent() {
  this.outputEvent.emit('className');
}
```

**button-wrapper.component.html**

```
<app-button (outputEvent)="handleEvent($event)"></app-button>
```

**button-wrapper.component.ts** (selector: app-button-wrapper)

```
handleEvent(e) {
  this.outputEvent.emit(e);
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-button-wrapper (outputEvent)="handleEvent($event)"></app-button-wrapper>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
handleEvent(e) {
  myClass = e;
}
```